# In C++ why is ifstream getline returning every other number in my .txt file, rather than all of them?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

When I run this code it doesn't print the contents of the .txt file which is numbers 1 to 100, it prints all of the even numbers up to 100 (e.g. 2 4 6 8 so on.) And I don't know why, it didn't before and I don't think I changed anything. I'm using xcode. Anybody got any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <iostream>     
#include <cmath>        
#include <string>       
#include <sstream>      
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    int Points[100];
    ifstream myfile("StatNum.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            getline(myfile,line);
            stringstream(line) >> Points[100];  //uses stringstream to convert Myline (which is a string) into a number and put it into an index of Points
            cout << Points[100] << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should go through your code line by line and explain each one to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). The issue will become obvious.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: line collected by `while ( getline (myfile,line) )` is simply thrown away/unused. Then you move to next line(even line num).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you call `getline` twice per iteration:

- First, you call it in the `while` header
- Then you call it inside the loop.

One invocation (the one in the `while` header) is sufficient, because the result is saved in the `line` variable, which the loop body is free to examine.

Removing the second invocation will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @dasblinkenlight pointed out, you are calling `std::getline()` twice and that's the problem that you see.

The problem that you can't see is that you are writing data to `Points[100]` which is an invalid location, outside of the array's bounds. The 100 valid locations in your array are indexes 0 to 99, that is `Points[0]`, `Points[1]`, ..., `Points[99]` (because counting in C++ starts from 0, not 1).

Writing to `Points[100]` is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239977/7023624) which means that your program may crash, or worse: may not crash while corrupting its own data.

Since you're using C++ you have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and other [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) at your disposal, where you can easily store the numbers you read:

```cpp
#include <vector>

// ...

vector<int> points;

while (getline(myfile, line))
{
    int temp;

    stringstream(line) >> temp;
    points.push_back(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```